# Remove the table and just display information Message

Tags: jquery

Enter some keyword under Search Input (Other than **One & Two**) and click on search button .It displays a message as "**Nothing Exists**"

Is it possible to remove the table and just display the information message ?

```js
var infoarray = ["ONE", "TWO"];
$(document).ready(function() {});

function showAllTags(searchTerm) {
  var tagsres = infoarray.length;
  var taghtml = '';
  var found = $.inArray(searchTerm, infoarray) > -1;
  if (!found) {
    taghtml = 'Nothig  Exists'
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < infoarray.length; i++) {
      var tag_name = infoarray[i]
      var tag_id = i + 1;
      taghtml += '<tr id=' + tag_id + '  tag_id=' + tag_id + ' style="cursor: move;">\
      <td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + tag_id + '</td>\n\
      <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><span id="span' + tag_id + '">' + tag_name + '</span></td>\n\
      <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editTagname"  data-tagid=' + tag_id + '  data-tagname="' + tag_name + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary editcatclick"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a><a href="#" class=" btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash"></i> </a></td>\n\
      </tr>'
    }
  }
  $("#alltagstable tbody").html(taghtml);
  $("#alltagstable").show();
  return false;
}

$(document).on("click", "#button2", function(event) {
  var searchTerm = $.trim($("#searchinput").val());
  showAllTags(searchTerm);
});
```

```css
.pageMidLogo {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.createAccountWrap {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.createAccountWrap .h3_head {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px !important;
}
.iLabel {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.insideInput {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltipIcon {
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 16px;
  background: #ababab;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.tooltipIcon:before {
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}
.pop_tooltipIcon {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #d03e43;
}
.iconPinReload {
  /*background: url(../images/icon-capthareload.png) 10px 10px no-repeat #f6f6f6;
 border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
 width: 52px;
 height: 41px;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
}
/*.iconPinReload:hover{
 background: url(../images/icon-capthareload.png) 10px 10px no-repeat #f0f0f0;
}*/

.tpMenuWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 88%;
}
.btMenuWrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 88%;
}
.ul_menu {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.ul_menu li {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.ul_menu li a {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ddd;
}
.ul_menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.panelCloseBtn {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #777 !important;
}
.panelCloseBtn:hover {
  color: #999 !important;
}
.homeListMenuWrap {
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li {
  padding: 25px 25px 20px 25px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li a:hover {
  color: #d03e43;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li .qrcode {
  background: url(../images/icon-QRcode.png) left top no-repeat;
  padding-left: 120px;
  display: block;
  color: #314158;
  min-height: 110px;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li .homedeliver {
  background: url(../images/icon-homedelivery.png) left top no-repeat;
  padding-left: 120px;
  display: block;
  color: #314158;
  min-height: 110px;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li .qrcode p,
.homeListMenuWrap li .homedeliver p {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.qrcode_errorWrap {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.qrcode_errorWrap .qrcodeError {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 26px !important;
  margin-bottom: 25px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}
.orDivider {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px !important;
  font-style: italic;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.orDivider span {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.orDivider .hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
/* Tree Menu Start */

.TreeMenu {
  width: 100%;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-heading {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-heading a {
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border: 0px !important;
  background: #fff;
}
.TreeMenu_Content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_left_aside {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl .vegLabel {
  background: url(../images/veg_labels.png) left 3px no-repeat;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl .nonvegLabel {
  background: url(../images/nonveg_labels.png) left 3px no-repeat;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl h3 .prdDiscription {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 1px;
  width: auto !important;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl .addonsList {
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_img {
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  float: left;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_img img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside .trashBtn {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside p strike {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside p b {
  font-weight: 600;
}
/* Tree Child */

.TreeMenuChild .ui-collapsible-content {
  padding: 0px;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-icon-plus:after {
  background-image: url(images/icons-png/carat-r-black.png) !important;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-icon-minus:after {
  background-image: url(images/icons-png/carat-d-white.png) !important;
  background-color: #d03e43;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle:last-child {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.addonsBtn {
  width: auto !important;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.addonsBtn a {
  color: #333 !important;
}
.Itm_discrp {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.Itm_discrp h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  padding: 0px;
}
.Itm_discrp p {
  text-align: justify;
}
.Qty_Wrap {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.Qty_Wrap .QtyBtn {
  float: left;
  width: 33px;
  border-radius: 34px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.Qty_Wrap .QtyBtn:before {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.Qty_Wrap .ui-input-text {
  float: left;
  border: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.Qty_Wrap .QtyInput {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 1.6em;
}
.addonsContent h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction {
  float: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: -28px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction a {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction a.tick {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction a.remove {
  color: #333;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul li:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul li.active {
  border: 1px solid #d03e43;
  color: #d03e43;
}
.addonsContent .popup_content_addonsWrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap {
  width: 100%;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li form {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: auto;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li .ui-mini {
  margin: 0px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li .ui-mini label {
  background: #fff !important;
  border: 0px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(208, 62, 67, 0.9);
  border-top: 2px solid #d03e43;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer:hover {
  background: rgba(208, 62, 67, 1);
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner:after {
  content: '\e988';
  font-family: "fontello";
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 37px;
  position: absolute;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .myorders,
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal {
  float: left;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .myorders {
  padding: 12px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .myorders i {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 120px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal {
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal b {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal b span {
  font-size: 22px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal .minOrder {
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
/*.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right{
 width:85%;
 float:left;
 padding-left: 12px;
}*/

/*.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right .subtotal{
 font-size:18px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right .subtotal span{
 margin-left:10px;
 font-size:24px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right .subtotal i{
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 font-size:13px;
 font-style:normal;
}*/

/* My Order page start */

.MyOrdersPage {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}
.MyOrdersPage .TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.vendorNameDtsl {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.vendorNameDtsl h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 4px !important;
}
.vendorNameDtsl span {
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl li span {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl li.totalsection {
  padding-top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #d03e43;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
/*.orderSummary_priceDtsl .inclusiveTax{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 margin:30px 0px !important;
}*/

.customerNameDtl {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.customerNameDtl_left {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
.customerNameDtl_right {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
.customerNameDtl_right .totalsection {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  color: #d03e43;
}
.customerNameDtl_right .totalsection span {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.customerNameDtl_right button {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* My Order page end */

.placeorderimg {
  width: 176px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.cancelOrder {
  width: 100% !important;
  float: left;
  padding: 18px 0px !important;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.commentWrap {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
.commentWrap textarea {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Input field:
  <input type="text" id="searchinput">
</p>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Search" />

<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" id="alltagstable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="40%">S No.</th>
      <th width="40%">Tage Name</th>
      <th width="10%">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/433/

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question. I updated it for you in this case

Answer (score 0):

Hope that's what you want to do. Have a look on JS fiddle code :)

[JS fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/rajkaushik05/cod7ceho/434/)

HTML

```
<p id="showErrorMsg"></p>
```

JS

```
function showAllTags(searchTerm)
{
        var tagsres = infoarray.length;
        var taghtml = '';
        var found = $.inArray(searchTerm, infoarray) > -1;
        if (!found)
        {
                taghtml = 'Nothig  Exists';
                $("#alltagstable").hide();

                $('#showErrorMsg').text(taghtml);
        }
        else
        {
                for (var i = 0; i < infoarray.length; i++)
                {
                        var tag_name = infoarray[i]
                        var tag_id = i + 1;
                        taghtml += '<tr id=' + tag_id + '  tag_id=' + tag_id + ' style="cursor: move;">\
                         <td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + tag_id + '</td>\n\
                 <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><span id="span' + tag_id + '">' + tag_name + '</span></td>\n\
                  <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editTagname"  data-tagid=' + tag_id + '  data-tagname="' + tag_name + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary editcatclick"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a><a href="#" class=" btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash"></i> </a></td>\n\
            </tr>'
                }
                $("#alltagstable tbody").html(taghtml);
        $("#alltagstable").show();
        $('#showErrorMsg').hide();
        }

        return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry. now i just update and shared new link
http://jsfiddle.net/rajkaushik05/cod7ceho/434/

Answer (score -1):

Easy way is to have a `div` placed just before the table, initially hidden, like:

```
<div id="nothingExists" style="display:none">
Nothing exists
</div>
```

and then change your if condition like:

```
///// existing code
if (!found) {
  taghtml = 'Nothig  Exists'
  $('#alltagstable').hide();
  $('#nothingExists').text(taghtml);
  $('#nothingExists').show();
  return false;
} else {
///// existing code
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/435/)

BTW, looking at your high reputation I'm surprised to see such a simple question from you. Or is it that I'm not getting your question? :)